# How to avoid multiline TextBox Enter keypress is swallowed when using InputBindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm doing WPF MVVM and have the following XAML code:

```xml
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Name="Console" MinWidth="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" AcceptsReturn="True" CharacterCasing="Upper" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Cursor="IBeam">
  <TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=Console}" Key="Enter"/>
  </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

When handling the Enter press in the ViewModel's command property (initialized in constructor with event handler added):

```cs
private readonly MyCommand myCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand
{
  get
  {
    return myCommand;
  }
}

private void OnCommand(object sender, MyCommandEventArgs e)
{
  <do something>
}
```

The event handler is called allright, but the Enter keypress is never passed back to the TextBox and the newline is not added (the cursor stays on the same line).

Doesn't event bubbling ensure that the Enter keypress gets passed on to the TextBox?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of this [WPF Terminal](http://wpfterminal.codeplex.com/) - I'll need a more lightweight version though, but subclassing TextBox seems like the way to go. Need to figure out a MVVM approach.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add "\n" to your textbox' Text-value?

(Would have add that as a comment but I may not do that yet...)

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I imagined :) Nevertheless, remember I'm doing MVVM, so using your suggestion I tried binding the TextBox Text to a string property (on the VM) and when setting this property (part of command handling) adding an "\n" to the string. The result is that the TextBox line just written "disappears" at the top, leaving the cursor ready at line 1